# How to reset esp8266 NodeMCU?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I'm new at NodeMCU.  My NodeMCU version is LOLin 0.1

First code I have uploaded is Spacehuhn's Deauther.  I set up my AP for deauther settings and everything worked fine.

Few days later I wrote a new code (related with WIFI) and it didn't work.  Then, I looked at WIFI and it say **my old AP (which should be overwritten)**

*Is there any way to Factory reset the NodeMCU?*

I tried flashing 1MB of nothing into **0x000000 0x100000 0x200000 and 0x300000**. It looked like it worked but when I checked back to Arduino IDE and upload my new code again, that AP come back, but in different name (change into **ESP_1B24B6**)

Maybe problem is at ***Arduino IDE*** or ***NodeMCU***

Comment: Share your WiFi setup code please.

Comment: It's here --> https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther   -Some files in Arduino IDE have been replaced in this project but i reinstalled Arduino IDE , nothing happen.

Comment: network config is not changed by firmware. in arduino, you need to call `WiFi.disconnect();` before you give it new settings.

Answer (score 5):

Since you did not give the versions of the software this works under the following conditions:

```
 Arduino IDE 1.85
 ESP8266 package 2.42 (min 2.41)
```

check in

```
 ArduinoIDE -> Tools -> board manager
```

Then in the boardmanager choose

```
 NodeMCU 1.0 under the heading ESP Modules (!)
```

**NOT** under the heading deauther !!

Before flashing choose your values for the port and the board under

```
 ArduinoIDE -> Tools ->
```

To get rid of the old wifi settings you have two options in

```
 ArduinoIDE -> Tools -> EraseFlash -> Sketch and WifiSettings **or** AllFlash Contents
```

This works for sure if the IDE responds 100% flash and no warnings/errors under the heading

```
 esptool v0.4.13 - (c) 2014 ....

     setting board to nodemcu
     setting baudrate from xxx to xxx
     setting port from COMxx to COMxx

 in the console (xxx - your choosen values)
```

For older IDE or ESP package version this is probably not possible or some menu items may not available.

Comment: This worked, but I need to add that you have to re-upload you program. Also, make sure to change that setting afterwards because it will erase everything every single time you flash to the esp8266.